# Individual Observable Collections vs Filtered Observable Collection performance

Tags: wpf

What is faster for a Large Collection binding for example,

Requirement - e-trading application:

Price Blotter - That displays Quotes/Trades for Different Securities for example.

**Master View** - Displays all quotes.

**Country View** - displays quotes/trades for securities belonging to a particular country. E.g. UK/France etc.

Currently - We have observable collection for each view, and when a price arrives from server, we send a copy to each Observable collection based on the filter i.e. one to Master view, and based on country to Country view for example.

**Question:** Does filtered observable collection outperforms this model even though CollectionViewsource will require a refresh when a price is added/Deleted. Does refresh the CollectionView source adds any performance penalty.

Example above is just for reference, there can be as many as 20 different views, and as many as 20-50K, with 5-6K unique prices each having a very big price depth intraday. Application has high demand in terms of GUI performance.

I am planning to replace the current Datagrid with a light weight Tableview, wondering if a single master Observable collection will help as well.

Many Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: How many views do you expect the user to have open at any single moment? If you have one master observable collection, and you add/remove an item from the collection, then **all** references to that collection will update their bound element. Let's say you had 20 views open, that's 20 UI updates you have to work with.

Comment: Let's assume - All 20 views. Blotter is a control with each view as Tab.

All references to the view will update bound elements is fine - But the underlying "Filtered" CollectionView will have filtered records, no?

e.g. Master Observable Collection has 5 Records (UK, Germany, USA, SPAIN, ITALY) - Master view displays all 5, UK Displays 1 and so on. New element added (UK), Master will have 6, and UK will have 2, others still empty and so on. 

Currently achieved using each view having it's own ObS Col. Messaging layer routes to appropriate view based on Country and View Type, Just for example.

Comment: Have you tried using an ICollectionView(s) to display a filtered representation of your single observable collection. With virtualisation enabled on your UI control performance should be good even with a lot of data.

Comment: I had 5 tabs with average 5000+ orders in UserView, GroupView (even more order), AccessibleView (even more than group), CompletedView, CustomFilterView. No performance problem using the FilterCollection approach. I believe you are using DevExpress or Infraguistic that have Virtualization turns on by default already. Anyway, there's 2 types of Grid update and use Begin/End update in batch when you update the FilteredCollection in background thread ?

Comment: In a similar project I created my on CollectionView with an underlaying list that supported data virtualization. I impelemented sort of paging mechanism in the virtual dataset and transfered the filtering expression to the server side. Combining with UI virtualization in a DataGrid, the CollectionView serves the data by index. Using a WCF service the visible rows can be loaded in a separate thread just in miliseconds. With a fast server the view does not even blink. The users can scroll through the whole list without being hold by the UI. I can share the code in an answer, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Refreshes on a `CollectionViewSource` can be very bad for performance as it will cause the items and item containers in your view to be regenerated (see link in next sentence for reference). This is the whole reason that there are [Editable Collections](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/10/20/itemscontrol-e-is-for-editable-collection/) in WPF. I have implemented large modifiable collections for a product once and I never ran into performance issues when I was using `IEditableCollectionView` although that isn't to say that it might not be fast enough for your application.

My guess is if you are using `IEditableCollectionView` it won't matter much if you split the collections up or keep them all together in one giant collection with different filters applied.